# VBA Convert Date

Tags: excel, vba

What am I doing wrong ?

in cell a2 I have a date (US) format 19790131. I would like to have this rewritten in 31.01.1979 `enter code here`But get the result: 1/31/1979

```
For i = 2 To z
DatText = Cells(i, x)
Cells(i, x) = CDate(Mid(DatText, 7, 2) & "." & Mid(DatText, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(DatText, 1, 4))
Cells(i, x).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slashes instead of periods so `CDate` will understand it.

```
Cells(i, x) = CDate(Mid(DatText, 7, 2) & "/" & Mid(DatText, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(DatText, 1, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But that's not it.

Comment: Odd, since it worked perfectly fine when I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is a **"real" Excel date**, with a cell format of `"yyyymmdd"`, then you just need to change the cell format to `"dd.mm.yyy"`

If the date is the **actual number:** `19790131`, then you have to convert it first to a real date. Try:

```
Function dtNumToDt(n As Long) As Date
    Dim yr As Long, mn As Long, dy As Long
    
yr = Left(n, 4)
mn = Mid(n, 5, 2)
dy = Right(n, 2)

dtNumToDt = DateSerial(yr, mn, dy)

End Function
```

And then format the cell (numberformat) as `"dd.mm.yyy"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Format* for this - and include *IsDate* for a little error handling:

```vb
Public Function ConvertDate()
    
    Dim ThisCell    As Excel.Range
    
    Dim RowIndex    As Long
    Dim ColumnIndex As Long
    Dim DatText     As String
    
    ColumnIndex = 1

    For RowIndex = 2 To 10
        Set ThisCell = Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)
        If Not IsDate(ThisCell.Value) Then
            DatText = Format(ThisCell.Value, "@@@@\/@@\/@@")
            If IsDate(DatText) Then
                ThisCell.Value = CDate(DatText)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```